# Multisite + wp_mail - Route Via Site Conditionally

Tags: multisite, wp-mail

I'm using a multisite and would like to send emails via specific/conditional sites. My use case:

- On `save_post`...
- a) send email to User A of Parent Site 1
- b) send email to User B of Child Site 2

I'm guessing that I need to 'break' the current site, temporarily override it with a specific site ID, and then restore the current site...I just don't know how to do it:

My initial code:

```
function conditional_multisite_wp_mail( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

    $to1 = 'hi@meow.com';
    $to2 = 'hola@miau.com';
    $subject = 'testing right meow';
    $message = 'woof';
    $headers = 'From: Derp  < derp@herp.com > \r\n';

    // Trying to 'break' current site, set the site by ID
    switch_to_blog(2); 
    wp_mail( $to1, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );
    // ... then restore it to the current site
    restore_current_blog();
    wp_mail( $to2, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );


}
add_action( 'save_post', 'conditional_multisite_wp_mail', 10, 3 );
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess this works:

Note: I'm using [Postman SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postman-smtp/); for the example below to work, I imagine that you have to have your server/transactional email delivery service properly configured for each respective 'from' email

```
function conditional_multisite_wp_mail( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    $to1 = 'hi@meow.com';
    $to2 = 'hola@miau.com';
    $subject1 = 'SPECIFIC: testing right meow';
    $subject2 = 'CURRENT: testing right meow';
    $message = 'woof';
    $headers1 = 'From: Derp  < derp@herp.com > \r\n';
    $headers2 = 'From: Herp  < herp@derp.com > \r\n';
    switch_to_blog(1); // Switch to specific site
    wp_mail( $to1, $subject1, $message, $headers1, $attachments );
    restore_current_blog(); // Restore to current site
    wp_mail( $to2, $subject2, $message, $headers2, $attachments );


}
add_action( 'save_post', 'conditional_multisite_wp_mail', 10, 3 );
```